# Extract frames from video using ffmpeg -- frame accurate?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to extract highest quality frames from a video. I'll be using **`ffmpeg`** this way:

```
ffmpeg -i source_vid.mp4 -ss 15:10.123 -to 15:11.249 frames/frame_%03d.png
```

My questions:

1. Will `ffmpeg` automatically find a 'proper' frame w.r.t. the `-ss` time, or will it 'interpolate' between two frames if the `-ss` time doesn't fall accurately on the timing of a frame?
2. If the answer to the above question is 'interpolate', how do I ensure that I get the exact 'proper' frame instead of an 'interpolated' frame?

(I apologize if the terms I used are not accurate or correct; feel free to correct my terminologies)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have specified `ss` and `to` as output options, FFmpeg will generate all frames from beginning of file but discard them till start position is attained. Move those options to before the input.

```
ffmpeg -ss 15:10.123 -to 15:11.249 -i source_vid.mp4 frames/frame_%03d.png
```

FFmpeg won't interpolate unless a filter is specified.

For precise frame extraction by index, use

```
ffmpeg -i source_vid.mp4 -vf trim=start_frame=n:end_frame=m frames/frame_%03d.png
```

Comment: I thought only ss as input switch made it decode all frames...

Comment: When using `ss` as output switch, it can only check the timestamp after the output frame has been generated, so the input frame has been decoded and encoded to output format before ffmpeg can evaluate whether to keep it or discard.